# Regular expression match a or b pattern

Tags: python, regex

I've got a small problem with the regular expression library in python, specifically with the match method with different patterns:

```
import re
files = ["noi100k_0p55m0p3_fow71f",\
     "fnoi100v5_71f60s",\
     "noi100k_0p55m0p3_151f_560s",\
     "noi110v25_560s"]

for i in files:
    keyws = i.split("_")
    for j in keyws:
        if re.match(r"noi(\w+)k|fnoi(\w+)v(\w+)|noi(\w+)v(\w+)",j): 
            print "Results :", re.match(r"noi(\w+)k|fnoi(\w+)v(\w+)|noi(\w+)v(\w+)",j).group(1)
```

The results are:

```
Results : 100
Results : None
Results : 100
Results : None
```

When I would expect:

```
Results : 100
Results : 100
Results : 100
Results : 110
```

The only match is for `"noi(\w+)k"` it does not seems to test the other patterns but `re.match(a|b,string)` should check the `a` and `b` pattern no?

Comment: Instead of doing `if re.match(..): print re.match(..).group(1)` you should just execute `re.match` *once*, store that result and then do `if result: print result.group(1)`.

Comment: Usually I do that, for this snippet of code I didn't. But I totally agree with you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your groups are numbered from left to right; if *one* of the alternatives matches, then it is *that group* you need to extract.

You have 5 groups, either group 1, or groups 2 and 3, or groups 4 and 5 will contain a match:

```
for j in keyws:
    match = re.match(r"noi(\w+)k|fnoi(\w+)v(\w+)|noi(\w+)v(\w+)",j)
    if match: 
        results = match.group(1) or match.group(2) or match.group(4)
        print "Results :", results
```

would print the first matched `\w+` group in each alternative.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> files = ["noi100k_0p55m0p3_fow71f",\
...      "fnoi100v5_71f60s",\
...      "noi100k_0p55m0p3_151f_560s",\
...      "noi110v25_560s"]
>>> for i in files:
...     keyws = i.split("_")
...     for j in keyws:
...         match = re.match(r"noi(\w+)k|fnoi(\w+)v(\w+)|noi(\w+)v(\w+)",j)
...         if match: 
...             results = match.group(1) or match.group(2) or match.group(4)
...             print "Results :", results
... 
Results : 100
Results : 100
Results : 100
Results : 110
```

If you are not going to use of the other two captured `(\w+)` groups, remove the parenthesis to make picking the matched group a little easier:

```
match = re.match(r"noi(\w+)k|fnoi(\w+)v\w+|noi(\w+)v\w+",j)
if match: 
    results = next(g for g in match.groups() if g)
    print "Results :", results
```

which picks the first matched group that is not empty.

Your pattern could be further simplified if you accept `fnoi(\w+)k` as a possibility too:

```
match = re.match(r"f?noi(\w+)[kv](\w*)", j)
```

at which point there is only ever a `.group(1)`.